# c++ map to unsigned char arrays

Tags: c++, pointers, esp32, stdmap

I'm trying to pull weather icons from openweathermap.org api and display them on an ESP32 driven OLED display using the u8g2 library (Arduino IDE, C++11).

In the openweathermap.org weather api, 16 types of weather are defined as `const *char[]` such as `"01d"`, `"01n"`, `"02d"`, etc.

The u8g2 library uses unsigned char arrays to define icons in the XBM bitmap format. I have defined all icons like this:

```cpp
static unsigned char icon01d[] = {
   0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
   0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
   ...
}
```

An icon can be displayed on the OLED by:

```cpp
u8g2.drawXBMP( 96, 0, 32, 32, icon01d );
```

I wanted to use a std::map to link the strings from the weather api to pointers to the icons like:

```cpp
map< string, unsigned char[]* > WEATHER_ICONS = { 
  { "01d", &icon01d },
  { "01n", &icon01n },
  ...
};
```

and would then (in my fantasy) be able to display the appropriate icon like:

```cpp
u8g2.drawXBMP( 96, 0, 32, 32, *WEATHER_ICONS[ weatherIcon ] );
```

with weatherIcon being the `const *char[]` casted to a string.

I have tried various alternatives to setup the map:

```cpp
std::map< std::string, <<variable reference>> > WEATHER_ICONS = { 
  { "01d", &icon01d },
  { "01n", &icon01n }
};
```

With `<<variable reference>>` according to the table, I get various error messages:

| variable referenced used | error message returned |
| --- | --- |
| `unsigned char[128]*` | `template argument 2 is invalid` |
| `unsigned char[]*` | `template argument 2 is invalid` |
| `unsigned char*[128]` | `could not convert '{{"01d", (& icon01d)}, {"01n", (& icon01n)}}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, unsigned char* [128]>'` |
| `unsigned char*[]` | `could not convert '{{"01d", (& icon01d)}, {"01n", (& icon01n)}}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, unsigned char* []>'` |
| `unsigned char**` | `could not convert '{{"01d", (& icon01d)}, {"01n", (& icon01n)}}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, unsigned char**>'` |

None of the error messages are very helpful to me. It looks like I have arrived in 'c pointer hell'.

I see advice on stackoverflow to define a pointer to a pointer array such as `unsigned char**` but I'm missing enough detail to get it working.

What would be the right solution?

As a workaround, I have implemented it like:

```cpp
      if     ( strcmp( weatherIcon, "01d" )==0 ) u8g2.drawXBMP( 96, 0, 32, 32, icon01d );
      else if( strcmp( weatherIcon, "01n" )==0 ) u8g2.drawXBMP( 96, 0, 32, 32, icon01n );
      else if( strcmp( weatherIcon, "02d" )==0 ) u8g2.drawXBMP( 96, 0, 32, 32, icon02d );
      else if( strcmp( weatherIcon, "02n" )==0 ) u8g2.drawXBMP( 96, 0, 32, 32, icon02n );
      else if( strcmp( weatherIcon, "03d" )==0 ) u8g2.drawXBMP( 96, 0, 32, 32, icon03d );
      else if( strcmp( weatherIcon, "03n" )==0 ) u8g2.drawXBMP( 96, 0, 32, 32, icon03n );
      else if( strcmp( weatherIcon, "04d" )==0 ) u8g2.drawXBMP( 96, 0, 32, 32, icon04d );
      else if( strcmp( weatherIcon, "04n" )==0 ) u8g2.drawXBMP( 96, 0, 32, 32, icon04n );
      else if( strcmp( weatherIcon, "09d" )==0 ) u8g2.drawXBMP( 96, 0, 32, 32, icon09d );
      else if( strcmp( weatherIcon, "09n" )==0 ) u8g2.drawXBMP( 96, 0, 32, 32, icon09n );
      else if( strcmp( weatherIcon, "11d" )==0 ) u8g2.drawXBMP( 96, 0, 32, 32, icon11d );
      else if( strcmp( weatherIcon, "11n" )==0 ) u8g2.drawXBMP( 96, 0, 32, 32, icon11n );
      else if( strcmp( weatherIcon, "13d" )==0 ) u8g2.drawXBMP( 96, 0, 32, 32, icon13d );
      else if( strcmp( weatherIcon, "13n" )==0 ) u8g2.drawXBMP( 96, 0, 32, 32, icon13n );
      else if( strcmp( weatherIcon, "50d" )==0 ) u8g2.drawXBMP( 96, 0, 32, 32, icon50d );
      else if( strcmp( weatherIcon, "50n" )==0 ) u8g2.drawXBMP( 96, 0, 32, 32, icon50n );
```

which works, but is not very elegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C and C++ evaluating a name of an array produces a pointer to the first value in the array.

Your `static unsigned char icon01d[]` is really an `unsigned char *`, in disguise. So:

```
map< string, unsigned char* > WEATHER_ICONS = { 
  { "01d", icon01d },
  { "01n", icon01n },
  ...
};
```

It is unclear from your question whether or not it is necessary to know the size of each such array. If all of these `unsigned char` arrays are the same size, well, there you go. Otherwise, perhaps, you can store both, spitballing something like this:

```
map< string, tuple<unsigned char*, size_t> > WEATHER_ICONS = { 
  { "01d", {icon01d, sizeof(icon01d)} },
  { "01n", {icon01n, sizeof(icon01n)} },
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first example call to `drawXBMP` you have:

```
u8g2.drawXBMP(96, 0, 32, 32, icon01d);
```

So, what is `icon01d` in this case? Since you are passing the name of an array without an index, your are actually passing a pointer to the first element in the array. In this case it is an `unsigned char*`.

When you declare your map, that is what you should be using. Like this:

```
map<string, unsigned char*> WEATHER_ICONS = {
```

Then you should call `drawXBMP` like this:

```
u8g2.drawXBMP(96, 0, 32, 32, WEATHER_ICONS[weatherIcon]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the solution is:

```cpp
std::map< std::string, unsigned char (*)[128] > WEATHER_ICONS = { 
  { "01n", & icon01n },
  { "02d", & icon02d },
```

Don't ask me how I found out..

Thanks both for trying to answer the question, I'm sorry if the question was not clear.